# Docker + any command not working, only /usr/local/bin/docker + any command works

Tags: docker

Only can use docker command with `/usr/local/bin/docker`. The command `docker` will not work.

Using MacOS

[details on the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvL40.png)

Comment: Please check if /usr/local/bin is present in PATH environment variable.

Comment: I checked your 'PATH' output, I see there is a dot in front of your '/usr/local/bin' which would cause the issue. So, you need to get rid of it to work properly.

Comment: @kite Thank you so much. export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/ solved my problem.